# Docker Stunnel - Finding the IP address

Tags: docker, docker-compose, stunnel

When creating a new container, docker will also create a new IP address. I'd need this IP address for the config file of my stunnel.

In other words, how do I setup stunnel with docker properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're setting up stunnel *inside* the container, you can just run `ip addr show eth0` to get your ip address:

```
/ # ip addr show eth0
61: eth0@if62: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.19/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:13/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

If you're setting up stunnel somewhere with access to the Docker API, you can use `docker inspect`:

```
$ docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' mycontainer
172.17.0.20
```

If you're trying to do something else, please update your question to be more explicit.